# Write separate functions for transforming the array and for reordering the elements

Tags: c++

i have a problem with the question and it works on Clion compiler but on Visual Studio Code gives me random values , also it gives random memory value on the university compiler and failed the test cases below text.

> An array of integers is to be read from SI. First the number N (N<=100) is entered followed by N integers. Write a program that will transform the array in the following way: starting at the beginning of the array, for each element that is equal to the next element in the array, double the value of the first one and overwrite the second one with 0. After that, rearrange the array so that all the zeroes will be moved at the end of the array, keeping the order of the other elements. Print all the elements of the array on the SO in a single line, separated by space.
> Write separate functions for transforming the array and for reordering the elements.
> Example:
> 6
> 2 2 0 4 8 8
> (Intermediate: 4, 0, 0, 4, 16, 0)
> Output:
> 4 4 16 0 0 0

And for this test cases it gives random memory value:

Input:

```
50
2 1 5 0 4 2 5 0 7 8 9 8 7 0 6 2 9 7 2 8 3 8 9 0 8 2 7 6 7 6 0 0 0 5 6 8 8 5 7 5 1 8 7 2 6 7 7 8 8 3
```

Output:

```
2 1 5 4 2 5 7 8 9 8 7 6 2 9 7 2 8 3 8 9 8 2 7 6 7 6 5 6 16 5 7 5 1 8 7 2 6 14 16 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Input:

```
5
1 0 3 3 3
```

Output:

```
1 6 3 0 0
```

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;




int check_for_equality(int array[],int n){
    for (int i = 0;i<n-1;i++){
        if (array[i] == array[i+1]){
            array[i] = array[i] * 2;
            array[i+1] = 0;
        }
    }
    int l = n-2;
    int r = n-1;
    while (l >= 0){
        if (array[l] == 0 && array[r] != 0){
            int temp = array[l];
            array[l] = array[r];
            array[r] = temp;
            l++;
            r++;
        }
        else{
            l--;
            r--;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<array[i]<<" ";
    }
}



int main(){
    int n = 0;
    cin >> n;
    int array[n];
    for (int i  =0;i<n;i++){
        cin >> array[i];
    }
    check_for_equality(array,n);

}
```

Comment: `int array[n];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by a compile-time constant, not a runtime value.  This should be `std::vector<int> array(n);`, and in doing that, you get much more diagnostic information available to you if you go out-of-bounds (by using the at() function).

Comment: *it works on Clion compiler but on Visual Studio Code* -- Also, CLion and Visual Studio Code are *not* C++ compilers.  They are simply code editors that will invoke the underlying compiler, which is probably `g++`.

Comment: Yea i know it is fixed size but we haven't reach that , i understand what you are talking about.But how my code will look if that's the case ?

Comment: *Yea i know it is fixed size but we haven't reach that* -- So your school or teacher is teaching how to use invalid C++ syntax?

Comment: Was this used on older C++ since we are learning that kind of C++ but by the way is my code on right way?

Comment: C++ never supported variable length arrays.  Also, your code will fail to compile if you happen to use Visual C++.  So your school is teaching invalid C++ that will not work on a compiler that is probably used by the majority of the world.  Also, if you compiled your code with the option `-pedantic-errors`, your code will fail to compile, whether you are using Clion or Visual Studio Code, since they probably use `g++`.

Comment: Even _if_ variable length arrays would be in the standard, your program would still have _undefined behavior_ since `check_for_equality` is declared to return an `int` but it does not. Make it `void` instead - at least until you know what to return from it. Also: `if (array[l] == 0 && array[r] != 0)` accesses `array` out of bounds. Print `r` to verify.

Comment: then what to do i am learner can you answer proper code?

Comment: @optimus If you used vector and `at()` as already suggested, you would have seen the error [easily](https://godbolt.org/z/TcrEzEWT7).  You are going out-of-bounds (look at the calls to at()).

Comment: I haven't learned that yet.

Comment: @opitimus So isn't this a good time to actually learn `std::vector`?  You see that it pinpointed the error you were making almost immediately.  There may be others, but it shows one location where your array accesses are out-of-bounds.

Comment: _"what to do"_ -Always make your functions return what you've declared them to return - or make them `void` and don't return anything.  If you can't use `std::vector<int>` for some reason and must resort to variable length arrays, then you need to check your bounds. Do `std::cout << l << ' ' << r << std::endl;` above `if (array[l] == 0 && array[r] != 0)` and you'll see that `r` goes out of bounds.

Comment: I also need to point out that `std::vector` has been officially part of C++ for **26 years**.  It isn't something new or "third-party".  It is part of the C++ library, and has been part of the library for over a generation.

Comment: @opitimus -- The code where you are multiplying the elements by two is ok (if variable length arrays were standard).  It is the second `while` loop, i.e. the moving the zeros to the end that is the problem.  The answers given shows this, plus there is a very easy way to move the zeros to the end without writing any loops, but that requires knowledge of the algorithm function `std::stable_partition`, which I assume you do not know of or learned yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your code, there's several problems as mentioned in the question comments. Regarding your logic, as also mentioned in the comments, there's a problem with your code to move all of the zeros to the right. In particular, consider

```cpp
    int l = n-2;
    int r = n-1;
    while (l >= 0){
        if (array[l] == 0 && array[r] != 0){
            int temp = array[l];
            array[l] = array[r];
            array[r] = temp;
            l++;
            r++;
        }
        else{
            l--;
            r--;
        }
```

For example, suppose that initially `array[l] == 0 && array[r] != 0` is true. Then your code will execute the `if` part, including switching the values around, so `array[r] = 0`, i.e., `array[n-1] = 0`. Also, the line `l++` will cause `l = n - 1` and the line `r++` which will result in `r = n`. However, in the next iteration of the `while` loop, your code will be checking that conditional again. Since `array[l] == 0`, the code will then try to check `array[r] != 0`, i.e., access past the end of the array, which is UB (Undefined Behavior)!

Instead, you want to basically move down any top non-zero values and then have the zero replace the last non-zero value. For that purpose, I suggest keeping track of the right-most zero position in `r`, starting with it being `n` as a "virtual" zero, and then `l` being the left-most position being checked. Thus, that section of your code would look something like this:

```cpp
    int l = n-1;
    int r = n;
    while (l >= 0){
        if (array[l] == 0){
            for (int i = l; i < r-1; i++){
                array[i] = array[i+1];
            }
            array[--r] = 0;
        }
        l--;
   }
```

Note that the above part of the algorithm that places all 0's last in the array could be replaced by one call to [`std::stable_partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition):

```cpp
std::stable_partition(array, array + n, [](int x) { return x != 0; });
```

Comment: Just a FYI -- that entire logic of shifting the zeros to the end can be done in one line by using `std::stable_partition(array, array + n, [](int val) { return val != 0; });`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Lol, two minds :-)

Comment: Yeah, almost at the same time too.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you for your edit to make the corrections to my code, as well as adding about how the functionality of moving the zeros to the end could also be accomplished with just one line of code using a `std` function.

Answer (score 1):

Variable length arrays are not part of standard C++. If supported they are a compiler specific extension. This likely explains the difference in behavior, since you are using a variable length array in `main`. Use a `std::vector<int>` instead. The behavior of that is standardized and includes bounds checking when using [`at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at).